# Spring Boot Logback - how to remove DEBUG SMTP in catalina.out

Tags: spring-boot, logback, tomcat8

I have a spring-boot application that uses Logback to logging.
I am using `RollingFileAppender` for my DEBUG and ERROR logs.
My problem is I am getting some `DEBUG SMTP` and other mail related logs in my `catalina.out` file.
I would like to have them recorded in my DEBUG file instead.

Below is my logback configuration (xml).

**Logback XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <property name="LOG_PATH" value="${logs.path.location}"/>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
        %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/iyotbihagay_debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/iyotbihagay_debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/iyotbihagay_error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/iyotbihagay_error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <if condition='property("profile").contains("dev")'>
      <then>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </then>
    </if>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <if condition='property("profile").contains("dev")'>
      <then>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </then>
    </if>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="WARN"
    additivity="false">
    <if condition='property("profile").contains("dev")'>
      <then>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </then>
    </if>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="java.sql" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <if condition='property("profile").contains("dev")'>
      <then>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </then>
    </if>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
  </logger>

  <root level="ERROR">
    <if condition='property("profile").contains("dev")'>
      <then>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </then>
    </if>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

**Logs (catalina.out):**

```
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO ecomm-dev2
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [101.78.249.147]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=bilatbasa@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<tomcat@ecomm-bilatdev2>
250 2.1.0 OK w127-v6sm20332821pfd.112 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<kataw.anan@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK w127-v6sm20332821pfd.112 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   kataw.anan@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead w127-v6sm20332821pfd.112 - gsmtp
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 21:24:26 +0800 (HKT)
Reply-To: no-reply@iyotbihagay.com
To: kataw.anan@gmail.com
Message-ID: <544564802.2.1539696266428@ecomm-bilatdev2>
Subject: Test mail profile staging 0004
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_356550530.1539696264700"

------=_Part_0_356550530.1539696264700
Content-Type: multipart/related;
        boundary="----=_Part_1_875170902.1539696264700"

------=_Part_1_875170902.1539696264700
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Any idea why the `DEBUG SMTP` and mail related bugs are showing in `catalina.out`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messages come from the class `com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger` and it looks like they go straight to a PrintStream (likely System.out, hence them showing up in catalina,out).

Here's the code that does logging:

```
public void log(Level level, String msg)
{
   ifDebugOut(msg);
   if (logger.isLoggable(level))
   {
      final StackTraceElement frame = inferCaller();
      logger.logp(level, frame.getClassName(), frame.getMethodName(), msg);
   }

private void ifDebugOut(String msg)
{
   if (debug)
      debugOut(msg);
   }

private void debugOut(String msg)
{
   if (prefix != null)
      out.println(prefix + ": " + msg);
   else
      out.println(msg);
   }
}
```

If you don't want to see them, you should be able to set a `spring.mail` property to disable debug logging on the mail session.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html

Comment: Thanks bro! I just add `spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=false` to my `application.properties` and it works!